# C# and Qt GUI Springs

Tags: c#, user-interface

I was wondering if there is an equilivant in C# of the GUI springs/spacers you can add in Qt which allows for easy window resizing.

Is there an easy way to keep forms looking ok when Maximised or resized in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to keep forms
>   looking ok when Maximised or resized
>   in c#?

A detailed article on making resizable WinForms http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6964/1954

You would use `Anchor` and `Dock` properties along with `Panels` when needed.